# HQL query for many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations, hql

I have two entities in Java, and I builded a many-to-many relationship, bidirectional. I am using JBOSS server and hibernate annotation mapping.

Patient entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "treats", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id") })
private List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
```

Doctor entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctor")
public class Doctor implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "doctors")
private List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

I want to query the doctors which are added to a patient. How to use HQL for this problem? I need to set parameter as well.
I tried with this method(it's in a DAO class):

```
public List<Doctor> getDoctorsForPatient(Patient patient) {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("from Patient doctors ");
    query.append("inner join Patient where patient in :patient");
    return getSession().createQuery(query.toString())
            .setParameter("patient", patient)
            .list();
}
```

I've also tried to query from the 'treats'(the n:m association table) table, but I've got an exception that it is not mapped.

Comment: There is no query required if your mapping is correct.please refer to following link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/

Comment: I think my mapping is correct, because when I looked the datas and tables in pgAdmin, then everything was fine. In Patient table the id a name for a Patient, in Doctor table the id nem name for a Doctor, and in treats table the two foreign ids of patient and doctor. I just don't know how to reach these informations.

Comment: `@JoinTable(name = "treats", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id") })`
This annotation creates the third table, called 'treats', am I right?

Comment: ohh sorry i missed it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The whole point of such an association is to be able to do `doctor.getPatients()` to get all the patients of a doctor. You don't need any query for that. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to show the Doctors which are related to a specific Patient on a JSF page. So you're saying, that `patient.getDoctors()` will store the related doctors automaticly with these hibernate annotations?